# Reloading a browser window when user switches away

Tags: javascript, jquery, browser, alert, onblur

I'm writing a quiz site for a client and the entrant gets 30 seconds to answer each question on the page. If they switch to another tab or the window blurs, I want that window to load an error page. This is based off jQuery code I used in 2015 which used to work fine, now when I test it, the "Leave site?" prompt pops up infinitely.

The old code used to be:

```
$(window).blur(function() {
 window.location = "<?=$server_url?>quiz_error.php"; 
});
```

I'm guessing the alert prompt itself is triggering another blur event and we are stuck in an infinite loop.
Is there a way to have this blur only trigger once so I can load the error page?
I tried

```
$(window).blur(function(e) {
 e.preventDefault(); 
 window.location = "<?=$server_url?>quiz_error.php"; 
});
```

but this didn't work either.

Many thanks :)

Comment: Looks like you need to stop the browser from showing the "Leave site" prompt. Probably because the browser registers some unsaved changes/modification on the page itself?

Comment: Yes, the user is answering quiz questions.

Comment: removeEventListener on blur?

Comment: I tried e.preventDefault(); but it didnt work...